# nopCommerce doesn't send Google E-commerce tracking at all?

Tags: nopcommerce

I am trying to get google e-commerce tracking set up on our nopCommerce site, and have tried several times, but can't seem to get it working.

Here are some screenshots of our setup:

[image: E-Commerce enabled on Google Analytics]

[image]

Not sure what we're doing wrong here, but i have followed some of the advice on this [thread on nopCommerce forum](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/41631/e-commerce-tracking-is-not-working-in-nopcommerce-340.aspx) but still it won't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What version of NopCommerce are you running?

I have been running 3.70 and just used the Google Analytics plugin - See here: http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/Google+Analytics+or+Universal+Analytics+Plugin

Just install the plugin then log into your Admin area > Configuration > Plugins > Local Plugins > Click 'Configure' on 'Google Analytics Or Universal Analytics'.

Then you just need to put your UA number linked to your Analytics account in the 'ID' box and hey-presto we should have e-commerce tracking.